# How to just keep the substring before the first blank character in one column?

Tags: python, string, pandas, find, substring

Here is my data sample:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                'Str':['aa aafae afre ht4','v fef 433','1234334 a','bijf 049tu0q4g vie','aaa 1']})
```

Now I want to just keep the substring before the first blank character. I can find the location of the first blank character. But I do not know how to do the next part.

I'm trying to print the first letters of the first three words of a sentence, but in the `d4 = y.find(" ", d3)` part, the program doesn't identify it as an integer, and if I convert it to an integer, it causes an error because I'm in base 10.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: import re, then before_blank_char = re.sub(" .*", "", x). If you consider a dash a blank character, you would pass "[ -].*" as the first argument instead. Also, if you know the location of the first blank character as y, you could use my_string[:y]. But regexes are handy and only take one line.

Comment: Thanks. But could you be more specific, like giving me a real example. I am really unfamiliar with these.

Comment: No problem. regexes seem tricky but some basics can go a long way. import re/x = "This is a sentence with only spaces"/y"This-here sentence has dashes"/x1=re.sub(" .*", "", x)y1=re.sub(" .*", "", y)/x2=re.sub("[- ].*", "", x)y2=re.sub("[- ].*", "", y)/print(x1, y1, x2, y2) (sorry for the bad formatting, in a rush, but replace / with carriage return). You should see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
a['Str'].split()[0]
```

to get the first substring before space.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use example string `this is just a test`

#### If the blanks are just spaces

You can do something like this:

```py
test = "this is just a test"
first_word = test.split(" ")[0]
print(first_word)
```

which will result in `this`

What I do here is

- splitting the string by spaces into array of words: `test.split(" ")`
- selecting only first element at position 0: `[0]`

#### If the blanks can be any whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc)

You can use regex like so:

```py
import re

test = "this is just a test"
first_word = re.sub('\s.*', '', test)
print(first_word)
```

Here I search for the first occurrence of whitespace ('\s') followed by any text (`.*`) and replace it with nothing (`''`).

#### If you want to use find

```py
test = "this is just a test"
space_pos = test.find(" ")
first_word = test[:space_pos]
print(first_word)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems not work well when it it a column.

Comment: @FengChen what does not work exactly? How do you put it in a column?

Comment: @FengChen my bad, I thought you want to *remove* part of the string before first blank.

Comment: No worries, Thanks a lot for your help. I use this way: a.loc[:,'Loc']=a.loc[:,'Str'].astype(str).str.find(' ')   ##---##    
a.loc[:,'Str'].astype(str).str[0:a.loc[:,'Loc']]. But it does not work

Comment: @FengChen I've updated the answer. Just use `your_string.split(" ")[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a['Str']=a['a'].str.split(' ') # split text using blanks
a['Str']=a['Str'].str.get(0) #get the first item of each Str column 
print(a)
```